# Asp.Net - User control with text between blocks

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I want to create a usercontrol that behaves like the `Label` usercontrol or the `HyperLink` usercontrol.

What I mean - the `Label` usercontrol has the `Text` attribute, and the text can also be set with the following way:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="lblTest">Text Here</asp:Label>
```

If I wish to create a usercontrol that can set the text between blocks to the actual `Text` attribute of the control.

Do I need to use Templated UserControl? If no - what is the correct way?

Thanks all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would create a simple custom control with the text attribute exposed as a property :-)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa310915%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: Although this works, it doesn't answer the question. There is a way to read text content in between the tags somehow.